# How to allow external process to launch my ASP.NET exe file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, self-contained

**UPDATED QUESTION**

I just deployed a self-contained solution to test my web app in an offline computer. When I go to the destination folder then double click on the executable I see the terminal window displaying that the ports http://locahost:5000 is open and https://localhost:5001 are open and ready to go. I then open a website and navigate to this url and sure enough I see my website working.

That takes care of part one.

Part 2 is launching my WebServer.exe from another application (called ProcessManager.exe)

This is where I am having issues...

Even though I am seeing the WebServer.exe application launching, I can't see any of the websites when I type: https://localhost:5001/SiteA. It tells me that it couldn't find the location of said url.

I go to my WebServer.exe application to see if its spitting out an error in the logs and I notice that the Content root path is wrong! It's telling me that it is looking for the contents of wwwroot folder in the wrong folder level.

Its saying Content root path:

```
E:\Projects\MyFirstProject\Deployments
```

I close everything and then I navigate to where my self-contained asp.net application is located and run WebServer.exe. Sure enough that one is displaying that it is pointing to the correct content root path which is:

```
E:\Projects\MyFirstProject\Deployments\WebServer
```

Another thing I notice when I launched my WebServer.exe from my ProcessManager.exe is that the WebServer.exe window also gives me this extra text at the very top:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
```

I did some minor research, and it turns out that my web application is not granting my ProcessManager.exe permissions of any kind. Or something to that effect.

This is how I am launchig my WebServer.exe from my ProcessManager project.

```
private const string WebServerPath = @"E:/Projects/MyFirstProject/Deployments/WebServer/WebServer.exe";     

 public ExternalProcess WebServerProcess
 {
       get { return _webServerProcess; }
 }
 private ExternalProcess _webServerProcess;

// constructor
public ProcessManager()
{
   _webServerProcess = new ExternalProcess(WebServerPath);
}

/// <summary>
/// Start the web server
/// Gets called in MainWindowViewModel.cs
/// </summary>
public void StartWebServer()
{
      string cmdLine = "";

      _webServerProcess.StartProcess(cmdLine);
}
```

As I mentioned before my ASP.NET application launches without any problems but it does give me that issue that I mentioned above... What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me understand what the underlying issue is?

many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you change any setting when you publish the project? I create a demo to test it and it works fine.

Comment: @XinranShen the only setting I change is where the self-contained deployment is sent. Before it was all getting deployed into the [Builds] folder but then I changed it to deploy into [Builds->Test] and then I proceeded to manually delete the old files that got deployed into [Build] including [wwwroot]